# Facebook App access token to manage pages without having user to login to get user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read alot of topis, alot of docs. Literally i read them since morning.

From what I got there are few kind types of tokens: App token, App access token, User Token, User access token, Page access token.

While tokens with `access` allow some kind of action. the `non-access` tokens seem to allow me to generate a token of `access` type. Corrent me if I'm wrong. Docs are terrible and some answers are outdated due to facebook updates.

So basically, what I look for is to be able to:

```
$permanent_token = 'A token, which will allow me to generate access tokens whenever I request';
// And that token could be used for:
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me/accounts/?access_token='.$permanent_token);
// Some code here to extract page access token and write it to variable $app_token
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{page_id}/ratings/?access_token='.$app_token);
// Note: I may've missed some steps... those are the ones I lack I think.
```

**Without** having to make any user (including me) to login. It's more like I need some kind of API Key and method to generate access token.

And would prefer **NOT to use** facebook SDK. Just pure graph url calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most import page to read about Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

**There is the App Token, the User Token and the Page Token. A User Token can be extended to 60 days, a Page Token can be extended to be valid forever.**

`/me/accounts` needs a User token, so there is no permanent Token to use that endpoint.

`/{page_id}/ratings/` needs a Page Token and you probably want an extended one.

How to get an Extended Page Token is explained very well int he Facebook docs, here are some articles:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Btw, i suggest not using file_get_contents but [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

**And in order to get a User Token or Page Token, you MUST authorize/login with a User account**. One that is admin of the Page, obviously.

Comment: I use file_get_contents to tests if it will work and if I can make it to work. Will be curl, since any 403 error does not return content so I can't debug at all with that. Realize that but thx for pointing it out. Also gonna go once again through those docs. All those tokens are a bit confusing I must admit.

Comment: there are only 3 tokens, and it´s pretty clear when to use which one. it´s not that confusing ;)

Comment: But those expiry times are. But from 2nd link you provided it seems that I need to write myself an app, using SDK that would generate for me permanent page access tokens. Since facebook UI does not allow this function. Right?

Comment: you don´t need any SDK. you can also just do this with the graph api explorer, as it´s explained in the articles.

Comment: Ah. 3rd link says it all. But I still need some kind of script to create permanent page access token (sorry for asking 2nd time. But want to be 1000% sure).

Comment: you MUST authorize a user for this, so you can´t do this with a script only, it has to be generated with user interaction. login > user token > extend user token > /me/accounts > get extended page token. that´s how it goes, i think it´s explained in the articles somewhere.

Comment: so you can use a script after the authorization, for extending the user token and calling /me/accounts with that one.

Comment: Yes. After analyzing scripts and documentation with information you provided I managed to write simple script to authorize user, create user access token, then extend it and then generate permanent app token! Very very thank you!

Comment: you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

If You are trying to get **photos and captions** like me, You could do like this:

1. Enter on facebook developer page: [facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com)
2. Create an app to the page. (I created to a not mine page)
3. Access on facebook developer menu: **Tools & support** and select **access token tools**.
4. There you'll find: User token - App token.(There some important text on the top)
5. **copy App token**. (should not be hard coded where is possible to see like on javascript)
6. create a php file to return a JSON.
7. use file_get_contents($url) function to get a facebook JSON.
8. echo the file_get_contents return.
9. finally, get on your page your own returned JSON from the created php file with the data desired and use it.

Obs: My URL is something like this: https://graph.facebook.com/desiredpage/photos?type=uploaded&access_token=013245667890|qwer-adsFGsfgsdGsfg
**pay attention to the token on the URL** that I **pasted**.